# How to disable v1 tag in a Web service request with SoapPy?

Tags: python, web-services, soappy

I'm trying to use SOAPpy to write a web service client. However after defining WSDL object, a call to a web-service method is wrapped in a

```
 <v1> .. actual parameters .. </v1>
```

How can I disable this v1 tag?

Comment: Can you provide the code snippet you used to generate the web-service call?

Answer (score 0):

You can give the name of tag by providing name in the parameter call list, i.e:

```
server.GetList(GetListRequest = { "order" : "asc" })
```

then `v1` is replaced by `GetListRequest` as I originally wanted.